# putting a next or previous control with many data using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a ajax in a div which putting all my data from my database in a panel bootstrap. How can i put something a next or previous if i have alot of populating data's from a div. Can anyone help me ? . Something, if the data is more than 10+, then the next/previous button will appear. Here is my code in ajax.

```
function show_patients(getClinicID) {
  $("#queue").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_patients/"+getClinicID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.length>0) {
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              $('#queue').append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+
                                  '<div class="panel-heading">'+'<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'">'+data[i]['order_num']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'<div id="patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+'<div class="panel-body">'+'<div class="row">'+
                                  '<div class="col-sm-5">'+'<small>Patient ID: <label id="patientID">'+data[i]['patient_id']+'</label></small>'+''+'<button onclick="checkstatus('+data[i]['patient_id']+');this.disabled=true;" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Check me up</button>'+'</div><!-- col-sm-4 -->'+'<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                                  '<div class="img-patient">'+'<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url('+data[i]['patient_photo']+')"></div>'+'</div><!-- img-patient -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->'+'</div><!-- row -->'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-body -->'+'</div><!-- panel-collapse -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
            };
          }
          else {
            $('#queue').append('<h4> No Patients in queue </h4>');
          }
        }
  });
}
```

Here is my populated view:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="col-title">
          <h4> Patients in Queue </h4>

          <div class="queue" id="queue">

          </div><!-- queue -->

          </div><!-- col-title -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination can be done qith jQuery and from PHP both. But if you have large data set pagination with PHP would be better.
Here is how you can use pagination with PHP(CodeIgniter)

For pagination you have to pass parameters to your request. Like which page you want currently. Other data like

- How many total records are
- How many records you want per page

That all you have to manage from PHP side (in your case codeigniter).

For that CodeIgniter has built-in [pagination library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html). Use this library and then build markup then append to DOM.

### Update:

For pagination in front side only, there are lots of libraries available like [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/), [Pagination.js](http://paginationjs.com/). There can be support for AJAX also, I haven't checked it.

Comment: can i make it, only a div ? next within a div ?

Comment: i mean, i populated my data inside a panel where it belongs to a 1 div. i want to something, if i click next, it will move only in a particular div ?

Comment: yes, it depends on how you are populating your data after AJAX call.

Comment: is it covered in what you have answered sir ?

Comment: If you choose pagination library in answer then it will handle all the things you just feed the data.

Comment: i go take a look study first sir . thanks. after i got it, i'll check ur answer. thank you sir